# Find the min/max value in a column of a DataTable with Where clause?

Tags: c#, select, datatable

Say for example I have this DataTable:

[image]

Is it possible to get the min/max value of Day1 column based on the Year column? Possibly using a select statement?

In SQL you would do:
SELECT MIN(Day1), Max(Day1) FROM TST WHERE Year = 2015

Comment: Have you tried looking at linq to datatable?

Comment: look at pivot to do what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you can do it in one statement, but you can do it in two using LINQ:

```
var minValue = tst.Where(t => t.Year == 2015).Min(t => t.Day1);
var maxValue = tst.Where(t => t.Year == 2015).Max(t => t.Day1);
```

`tst` needs to be something that LINQ recognises like a List, IEnumerable or Array.

You can use the [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/way3dy9w(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get an array from the DataTable, and even do the first filter:

```
var data = tst.Select("Year = 2015", "Day1 ASC").ToList(); // Not that you need it sorted
var minValue = data.Min(t => t.Day1);
var maxValue = data.Max(t => t.Day1);
```

Comment: Is the tst the name of the DataTable?

Comment: @John - yes. I copied it from the SQL in your question.

Comment: I tried tst and it says - Error 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @John you need to be using Linq. Sorry I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have included using System.Linq; as well as references to Linq (System.Data.DataSetExtentions and System.Data.Linq) and it does gives the same error. Edit: I see your new edit; tst needs to be a List, IEnumerable or Array.

Comment: If you call AsEnumerable() on tst the first Linq example would work.